# Populate CheckList from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to populate a list from my database.

I have the following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.pro);
    addProFromDB();

}
```

How I should populate the multi *xCodexInlinexPlacexHolderx*?

```
private void addProFromDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {
        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, 1, null);
        sampleDB.execSQL("create table tbl_product("
                + "pro_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
                + "pro_name text," + "pro_price integer);");

        sampleDB.execSQL("insert into tbl_product(pro_name, pro_price) values ('oil', '200' );");

        Cursor c = sampleDB.query(SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        char pro_nameColumnIndex = (char) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pro_name");
        int pro_priceColumnIndex = (int) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pro_price");

    } finally {
        if (sampleDB != null)
        sampleDB.close();
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, new ArrayList()));
```

It is not giving any error, but not showing the inserted items either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of issues are there in your code snippet.

1. You are creating table `tbl_product` every time you run you app.
2. You are inserting new element in your newly created table every time.
3. and finally you are passing empty array to your `ArrayAdapter` as
   `new ArrayList()`

I would recommend you to go through any tutorial, and sort out things step by step.

I'm suggesting you to follow [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview), and use `CursorAdapter` when you are working with sqlite.

Comment: thanks for your sugestions..i know its a v bad approach but in my scenario it fulfills the requiremnt.. i've 3 tabs, and on clicking each tab its relevant table is created.. can you please help me what part should i use to fill that empty array...thanks

Comment: [start from here for quick solution](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_database)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to modify your code, now you can check and use this code, this may helpful for you..

```
private void addProFromDB() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

try {
    list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, 1, null);
    sampleDB.execSQL("create table if not exists tbl_product("
            + "pro_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
            + "pro_name text," + "pro_price integer);");

    sampleDB.execSQL("insert into tbl_product(pro_name, pro_price) values ('oil', '200' );");

    Cursor c = sampleDB.query(SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES, null, null, null, null, null,
            null);
    char pro_nameColumnIndex = (char) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pro_name");
    int pro_priceColumnIndex = (int) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pro_price");

ArrayList list = new ArrayList()
list.add(pro_nameColumnIndex);
list.add(pro_priceColumnIndex);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, list));

} finally {
    if (sampleDB != null)
    sampleDB.close();
}
```

Comment: it doesnot display any data ...blank screen

Comment: Please go through this tutorial... clear out all concepts.. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview